# validate xml string against xsd using xerces-c++

Tags: xml, xerces, xsd-validation

how do i validate an xml string adainst xsd file using xerces-c++ library ? Is it possible with xercesDomParser ? If possible plz give an example. my xml string is as below
[cook]

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541064/xerces-c-xml-file-validation-with-xsd-file-c